# Apache2 RedirectMatch not working in specific case

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

I have a server using apache2 that redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain.com.au
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.mydomain.com.au/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com.au
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.mydomain.com.au/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

It works perfectly with the www domain but whenever I try to access the 'bare' domain I get the error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

The most baffling thing is that the HTTPS version works:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mydomain.com.au
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.mydomain.com.au/$1
        #...
</VirtualHost>
```

If I for example try to GET https://mydomain.com.au/contact, it will correctly redirect to https://www.mydomain.com.au/contact. However, it will fail if I do the same thing with HTTP. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have 2 entries for `VirtualHost *:80` You can use `ServerAlias` for `www` and have a single entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com.au
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com.au
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.mydomain.com.au/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

`ServerAlias` declares alternative names that can be used to address the same site as in `ServerName`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that my VirtualHost settings were being overwritten in sites-available/000-default.conf. I changed the  therein to have the configuration suggested by anubhava and it's working fine.